# General understanding \addplot3 pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

If I type into wolframalpha.com "3dplot (x+sin(x))^2" I get

[image]

When I use pgfplots and do this:

```
\addplot3[
surf,
opacity=0.8,
samples=50, samples y=30,
colormap/whitered,
domain=-1:1,y domain=-1:1,
z buffer=sort,
]
{((x+sin(x))^2};
```

I just get a normal 3-dimensional parabola.

Can anybody explain me the different outcomes?

Comment: Try with `domain=-3:3,`

Comment: You'll probably also need to use `sin(deg(x))` to convert `x` from degrees to radians.

Comment: @mrc: That was the issue. Thx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is because you have set a smaller domain, If you use `domain=-3.5:3.5` instead you get this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot3[
surf,
opacity=0.8,
samples=50, samples y=30,
%colormap/whitered,
domain=-3.5:3.5,domain y=-1:1
%z buffer=sort,
]
{((x+sin(deg(x)))^2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! The main problem was the conversion to degree in pgfplots. Cause I tried varying my domain ofc.